# Getting Push Button Logic To Stick?

Tags: programming, button

I'm trying to get a sensor to activate if a push button is clicked. And deactivate when a certain condition is met and reactivate when the push button is pressed again.

```
#include <SPI.h> // Included for SFE_LSM9DS0 library
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SFE_LSM9DS0.h>

#define LSM9DS0_XM  0x1D // Would be 0x1E if SDO_XM is LOW
#define LSM9DS0_G   0x6B // Would be 0x6A if SDO_G is LOW
// Create an instance of the LSM9DS0 library called `dof` the
// parameters for this constructor are:
// [SPI or I2C Mode declaration], [gyro I2C address], [xm I2C address]
LSM9DS0 dof(MODE_I2C, LSM9DS0_G, LSM9DS0_XM);

const byte INT1XM = 4; // INT1XM tells us when accel data is ready
//const byte INT2XM = 8; // INT2XM tells us when mag data is ready
//const byte DRDYG = 7;  // DRDYG tells us when gyro data is ready
const int buttonPin = 15;     // the number of the pushbutton pin

int buttonState = 0;


double X;
double Y;
double Z;

void setup(){

  pinMode(INT1XM, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);



  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600); // Start serial at 115200 bps
  // Use the begin() function to initialize the LSM9DS0 library.
  // You can either call it with no parameters (the easy way):

  uint16_t status = dof.begin();
  // Or call it with declarations for sensor scales and data rates:  
  //uint16_t status = dof.begin(dof.G_SCALE_2000DPS, dof.A_SCALE_6G, dof.M_SCALE_2GS);

  // begin() returns a 16-bit value which includes both the gyro and
  // accelerometers WHO_AM_I response. You can check this to make sure
  // communication was successful.
  // Serial.println(status, HEX);
  setODR();
}

void loop(){

  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin); //Read push button logic.

 // Serial.println(buttonState);

  if (buttonState == 1) {   //if push button is pressed

    printAccel(); //print sensor data

  }

}

void printAccel()
{
  // Only read from the accelerometer if the accel interrupts,
  // which means that new data is ready.
  if (digitalRead(INT1XM))
  {
    // Use the readAccel() function to get new data from the accel.
    // After calling this function, new values will be stored in
    // the ax, ay, and az variables.
    dof.readAccel();

    //Serial.print("A: ");

    // Using the calcAccel helper function, we can get the
    // accelerometer readings in g's.
    X=dof.calcAccel(dof.ax);
    Y=dof.calcAccel(dof.ay);
    Z=dof.calcAccel(dof.az);

    Serial.print(X);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.print(Y);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.println(Z); 

    // Serial1.println(Z);   

    fall(); //jump to check condition

  }
}

void setODR(){

  dof.setAccelODR(dof.A_ODR_25);
  dof.setAccelScale(dof.A_SCALE_16G);
}

void fall(){

  if(-0.08<X && X<0.08){
    if(-0.08<Y && Y<0.08){
      if(-0.08<Z && Z<0.08){

        Serial1.println("N");
        Serial.println("Fallen!");

        loop(); //if condition is met, jump to loop to wait for push button to be pressed again.

        }
      }
    }
  //else{

    printAccel(); //else continue printing sensor data

  //}
}
```

However I am having some trouble getting it to work, above is what I have worked out thus far.

Comment: What does your DFA look like?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm a little new to this, what does DFA stands for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to store whether the button has been pressed.

```
bool buttonActivated = false;

...

void loop(){

  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin); //Read push button logic.
  if (buttonState == 1 ) {
    buttonActivated = true;
  }

  if( buttonActivated ) {
    printAccel(); //print sensor data
  }

}
```

to deactivate, use:

```
buttonActivated = false;
```